# Path that is working with go run is not working with go install/calling the executable from bin

Tags: go

I'm starting to experiment with Go and I'm facing an issue that (I think) doesn't exist in languages that use a virtual machine.

I have a `src/test/main.go` file that references my templates inside `src/test/views/` folder.
When I use `go run main.go` it runs but when do `go install` and then inside my `bin` folder run the executable (`./test`) I get an error:

```
views/edit.html: no such file or directory
```

So, how does Go compiles my project (file/folder structure related) and how to use paths in a way that allows me to use either `go run` and `go install/executable`?

Comment: How is the html generated? Do you know where it is at compile time? You could use absolute paths or pass it in as a command line argument

Comment: @BenjaminKadish I'm having trouble understanding this...For example, if only one binary file is created I assume it has everything in it so path that are ok for go run should be ok for go install...I'll take a look at the libraries suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a relative path in your code, as in `views/edit.html` it will also be looked up relative to the binary location. You need to either make the path absolute, or use some logic to determine where your templates will be located.

Another option would be to use https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata or https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs that will save you the hassle.

Comment: So moving my binary file to the same folder as `main.go` would solve it. Do you see any issues with that when in production or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Well, yeah, that's a very straightforward approach. Depending on how you want to distribute your binary it might work it might now, it's quite dependant :) In general, if you are going to run it on a unix system, placing binary somewhere in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` would be advisable, and placing static resources somewhere under `/usr/share/appname` or so. That can be solved with packaging. Then you can use absolute paths. Ideally I'd make them configurable with sane defaults.